# MapBox SDK black screen on resume

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am using MapBox SDK on my android application, the map onCreate appears perfectly. I can add layers and show my markers and so on.
When the user clicks on a marker another activity is started. So I use mapView.onPause() on my onPause() method.
The issue appears when the user tries to go back to the map activity, I am using finish() method for that and once on the map activity a black screen replaces the map and the user can no more see the map and markers.
I figured out that the issue appears also when I lock the phone and come back to the application.
Any ideas about how to resolve that.

thank you very much.

Comment: check the errors in logcat.

Comment: Are you calling all of the required lifecycle methods? Here's the list:
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.onStart();
mapView.onResume();
mapView.onPause();
mapView.onStop();
mapView.onLowMemory();
mapView.onDestroy();
mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

Comment: Yes I am, but nothing seems to be working

Comment: I checked out the MapBox onResume to see what it does, I found that it calls mapRenderer.onResume() and this method is not implemented :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forgot to override onStart() method in my activity. 
I had to add it, and then the problem was solved.

Edit:

[Link](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/) to the Mapbox LifeCycle Methods.

Added code-snippet for onStart():

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }
```

Comment: I have added this in my fragment but its not working.In logcat it caught an exception  java.lang.Exception: Last location unavailable

Comment: try to open GoogleMaps and locate yourself, then retry it with your application.

Comment: Last location is often saved when we use maps application

Comment: Why is this like this.In some devices its ok but in some others its not ok.How can we handle the situation

Comment: actually, I think your not looking for the current location or your device is not able to find the current location, it's either your gps is off or you have no GPS signal,so it tries to restore the last location stored in your device. as you didn't have any last location (especially when you test with a virtual device) the application cant find a reference location

Comment: I am running on real device.Yes in my case gps is disbaled.